# Insecure after setting up SSL/HTTPS on my nginx server

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'm trying to set up HTTPS/SSL on my site `test.example.com`.

I edited my file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site` so that the top section of the `server {}` block is this.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;
    server_name test.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

    ... Rest of code ...
}
```

I ran `nginx restart`. But if I go to `https://test.testexample.com` in Chromium, my browser warns that my connection to the site is insecure.

Chromium error:

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from test.example.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server could not prove that it is test.example.com; its security certificate is from example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

My certificate was issued by Comodo. I'm following Namecheap's guide on integrating SSL into my site. Step 3: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/0/nginx

Comment: Your question is missing at least the exact error shown by the browser and also details about the certificate you've configured, i.e. self-signed or issued by a public CA. Once these information are provided one can probably see if the error is by design (i.e. self-signed will of course cause a browser warning) or by error (wrong setup of certificates).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Updated question

Comment: Again, don't use other people's domain names as your example.

Comment: You may need the certificate chain and a reference to it...

Comment: Run your site through this tool: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID   ...
>   This server could not prove that it is test.example.com; its security certificate is from example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

The certificate returned by the server does not match the name in the URL. Based on this description you've ordered a certificate for `example.com` but try to access the site as `test.example.com` which is not the domain the certificate was issued for.

This problem might be due to a wrong understanding of how the comparison of the domain in the URL against the certificate works. In general:

- A certificate is only valid for the domains explicitly mentioned in the subject alternative names section of the certificate (Chrome ignores CN). This means `example.com` does not match `test.example.com`.
- If you have a wildcard there can only be one `*`, it must be the leftmost label and it matches only a single part of the domain, i.e. a certificate for `*.example.com` will match `www.example.com` and `test.example.com` but not `www.test.example.com`.

Comment: My issue was thinking the wildcard covered more than one domain section i.e. `*dev.api*.site.com`. Changed to `dev-api.site.com` and it worked